# How to make slides with select transparency?

Tags: beamer, transparency

I checked out the Beamer manual and looked at 17.6 (the transparency section) but I cannot figure out how to do the following (and my lack of expertise with overlay must accent this).

What I want: I have a slide with objectives on them, and I want before each section to highlight the objective in question and dim the other objectives. This means I would have a slide with Objective 1 highlighted, and Objective 2 and 3 dimmed. Then I would discuss Objective 1. Once finished, I would have a new slide with Objective 1 dimmed, Objective 2 highlighted, and Objective 3 dimmed. I have provided code below, annotating what I mean.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Discussion}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Objectives}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Objective 1 % (highlighted)
    \item Objective 2 % (dimmed)
    \item Objective 3 % (dimmed)
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Objective 1} % Discussion of Objective 1

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{More List Types}
\begin{enumerate} [(I)]
\item Point A
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item part a
\item part b
\end{enumerate}
\item Point B
\item Point C
\item Point D
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Objectives}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Objective 1 % (dimmed)
    \item Objective 2 % (highlighted)
    \item Objective 3 % (dimmed)
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Objective 2} % Discussion of objective 2

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{More List Types}
\begin{enumerate} [(I)]
\item Point A
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item part a
\item part b
\end{enumerate}
\item Point B
\item Point C
\item Point D
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Objectives}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Objective 1 % (dimmed)
    \item Objective 2 % (dimmed)
    \item Objective 3 % (Highlighted)
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Objective 3} % Discussion of objective 3

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{More List Types}
\begin{enumerate} [(I)]
\item Point A
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item part a
\item part b
\end{enumerate}
\item Point B
\item Point C
\item Point D
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

I really appreciate the help! I've been asking loads of questions.

Comment: Remove the frame before each `\subsubsection`, and use `\subsection{Objective N} \frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection,subsectionstyle=show/shaded]}` for each subsubsection?

Comment: I have a table of contents already, so when I follow your code it just shows my previous TOC. :/

Comment: Is there any possible way to just make select items transparent, rather than using \setbeamercolored{transparent}?

Comment: But it dims the other subsections, does it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to do it manually. Just add the "transparent" uncover option to your preamble.

```
\setbeamercovered{again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}, dynamic}
```

And set each line of your enumerate environment manually to be highlighted or not.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \onslide<1> \item Objective 1 % (highlighted)
    \onslide<0> \item Objective 2 % (dimmed)
    \onslide<0> \item Objective 3 % (dimmed)
\end{enumerate}
```